# Post to rest API javascript not working

Tags: jquery, post

I am not sure why when I try click on submit button nothing happens and I just see the console log for session ID console.log('sessionID is' + sessionId); 
i pretty much need to be able to submit multiple object to a url , but even with one object I cant do it right now

```
 <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" />
  <br></br>
  <button id="button">Submit</button>
  <div id="status"></div>
</div> <td class="labelCol">
                        <label for="j_id0:j_id3:sessionId">
 session ID            </label>
                    <input id="j_id0:j_id3:sessionId" type="text" name="sessionId" class="PrequalStreet" style="width:246px;"
                            value="{!getSessionID()}"/>


</body>


<script>
$('#button').click(function(){
var sessionId = $( "input[id*='sessionId']" ).val();
console.log('sessionID is' + sessionId); 
  function createSobjectRecord() {
  console.log('I am in ');
   var accountInfo = {  "Name": $( "input[id*='name']" ).val()};
    console.log(' accountInfoJson ', accountInfo );
    var accountInfoJson = JSON.stringify(accountInfo);
    console.log('accountInfoJson ' + accountInfoJson );
    $j.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "me.com",
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'OAuth'+sessionId ,
             'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                      },
           data : accountInfoJson,
           success : function(response){
                        displayAccountInfo(response);
                        console.log('response',response);
                                },
           error: function(response){
                        displayError(response);
                                }
                            });

             }
                })
    </script>
```

Comment: Your click handler declares the `function createSobjectRecord()` but it never invokes it. So the ajax request is never made.

Comment: @Jasen isnt calling button.click calls everything with in it?

Comment: Yes, but you are declaring a new function within that. Just drop `function createSobjectRecord() { }` and make the ajax call. Or do a `createSobjectRecord()` within the handler.

Comment: yah I saw my mistake @Jasen thank you for pointing it out